# Emulator Not coming up

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-emulator

I am running an Android App very first time in IDEA IDE v 13. On running the program it is just showing this on console:

```
Waiting for device.
/usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/22.6/tools/emulator -avd Nexus7 -netspeed full -netdelay none
```

How long should I wait?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem: in my case waiting for 20 minutes doesn't suffice! You can read the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554099/why-is-the-android-emulator-so-slow) to get some hints to speed up your emulator.

Anyway I think the best way to test your Android app is on a real mobile device connected to your pc, but if you still need an emulator, [Genymotion](http://www.genymotion.com) is very fast compared to the other Android emulators.
There is a [free license](https://shop.genymotion.com/index.php?controller=order-opc) for non-commercial uses (if this is your case) which is enough for most of the cases.